# Imagemagick installed but Imagick class not found

Tags: php, imagemagick

When I run:

```
<?php exec("convert -version",$out,$returnval); print_r($out[0]); ?>
```

I get:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2012-05-07 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
```

But when I run:

```
$image = new Imagick($tiffImage);
```

I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in /home/content/...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't installed imagemagic php extension (.so or .dll) file to right place. Try reading this page:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php

In linux you need that .so and windows it is dll.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit new to this stuff, so I'm wondering if it's possible to install the extension on a shared hosting account, e.g. no dedicated server?

Comment: Could be really hard. You have to get access to change php.ini file and copy that extension to right folder.

Comment: Thanks, I can access php5.ini, so it looks like it's just a matter of copying the extension to the right folder

Answer (score 1):

Due to shared hosting, I wasn't able to install the imagemagick php extension, but I found this workaround:

```
<?php
try {
$cmd = "full-path-to/input1.tiff full-path-to/input2.png"; 
exec("/usr/local/bin/convert $cmd");
}
catch(Exception $e) {
die('Error when creating a file: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In debian, you install php5-imagick and you must restart apache2 server